# ruby on rails 4 validation and virtual attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm new to ruby on rails and I'm collaborating with some friends for an app. I notice that he did some validations that made no sense to me. I could ask him but he's not available until next week and he's also a beginner. So here's my situation. We have 3 models, doctor, specialization and institution:

**DOCTOR**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: doctors
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id           :integer
#  license_number    :string(255)
#  created_at        :datetime
#  updated_at        :datetime
#  specialization_id :integer
#  institution_id    :integer
#

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
        # relationships
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :shared_patient_cases
    has_many :patient_cases, through: :shared_patient_cases

    has_many :medical_examinations
    has_many :patients, through: :medical_examinations

    belongs_to :specialization
    belongs_to :institution

    # validations

    validates :specialization, presence: true
    validates :institution, presence:true
    validates :license_number, presence:true,  if: Proc.new { |a| a.specialization && a.specialization.licensed == 1 }
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :medical_examinations
end
```

**INSTITUTION**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: institutions
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  description    :string(255)
#  contact_number :string(255)
#  order          :integer
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#

class Institution < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doctors
end
```

**SPECIALIZATION**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: specializations
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  code        :string(255)
#  description :string(255)
#  order       :integer
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
#  licensed    :integer
#

class Specialization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doctors
end
```

Addional Info: VIEWS

https://gist.github.com/carlqt/8877706

I was wondering about the `validates :specialization, presence: true` and `validates :institution, presence:true` it's declared in the doctor model but the doctor model doesn't have those attributes. Does the doctor model inherited them when declared a `has_belongs` ? If not, how does it work?

Comment: Have you checked to confirm you can actually insert to the table and that the validations do actually allow that?

Comment: Yup. It's creating a doctor with the correct attributes and is associated with specialization and institution models. Seems that there's no problem in terms of the app but I want to understand to concept of it. As far as can tell, there might be some underlying consequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he is validating the relationship, you can check here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

which is connected to the field specialization_id

Comment: This makes sense! So additional question. Does it also check it the field is blank? I'm somewhat confused of the method.

Comment: yes it checks if the field is nil, be warned that a blank string is accepted.